# Proof that ${2p\choose p}\equiv 2\pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

While trying to prove that ${2p\choose p}\equiv 2\pmod p$, I saw a few successful methods, many of which seemed rather complicated or relied on obscure theorems (at least from the point of view of someone with my limited knowledge). Since I am quite new with number theory, I would appreciate it if someone could tell me if a method I came up with works, or, if not, where it goes wrong. My idea is that by expanding and reducing  ${2p\choose p}$, we get $$2\prod\limits_{i=1}^{p-1} \frac{2p-i}{p-i} \equiv 2\prod\limits_{i=1}^{p-1} 1 \equiv 2 \pmod {p}$$ because $2p-i \equiv p-i \pmod{p}$.

Is this valid? I know division$\pmod{p}$ is slightly weird, especially when the denominator is $\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, so I'm not sure if all of the statements I made are true. Let me know if I need to clarify anything, and thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

P.S. If there are any other [more accurate] proofs of this congruence that aren't too complicated, I'd love to see them.

Comment: I was going to object, but I think it is fine. Maybe we can add a bit of explanation in the first $\equiv$ to cast away the doubt. Let $2\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{2p-i}{p-i}\equiv a$. This is equivalent (because $p$ is prime and therefore relatively prime to the $p-i$'s) to $2\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}(2p-i)\equiv a\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}(p-i)$. This is equivalent to $2\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}(-i)\equiv a\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}(-i)$, which is equivalent to $2=a$ (where we have used again that $p$ is prime, and therefore relatively prime to all numbers smaller than it).

Comment: Do I have to make it that long, or can I just use $2p-i\equiv p-i \pmod {p}$ to prove that first $\equiv$ ?

Comment: or just add one line that $\{p+1,p+2,\ldots,2p-1\}$ forms a complete set of residues mod $p$, so that $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{p-1} (2p-i)(p-i)^{-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$

Comment: Note to self: $i$ is not always the imaginary unit. (I'm a little sleepy, but still took me waaaaay too long to figure that out)

Comment: These residues and characteristics are beginning to leave my realm of knowledge about modular arithmetic. Until I learn enough to understand them, I would be much obliged if someone could verify that $2p−i\equiv p−i\pmod{p}$ is all I need to complete this proof? I'll add what I think is the necessary addition to the first post.

Comment: If we put together the factors of $\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{2p-i}{p-i}$ in pairs as in $\frac{(2p-i)(2p+i)}{(p-i)(p+i)}=\frac{4p^2-i^2}{p^2-i^2}$ we can repeat the same simple arithmetic to get that the congruence is also satisfied mod $p^2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Incidentally, I just heard about this today. More can be said, in fact $p^2\mid \binom{2p}p-2$. Consider the set $A=\{x,y\}\times \Bbb Z_p$, and the collection $\mathcal C$ of subsets of $A$ of cardinality $p$, which you can think about boards of size $2\times p$ with entries in $\Bbb Z_p$ such that exactly $p$ entries are checked and $p$ are not, where we check the entry $(x,n)$ if $(x,n)\in S\subseteq A$.

We can make $\Bbb Z_p\times \Bbb Z_p$ act on the set $A$ as follows: if $(a,b)\in\Bbb Z$, we cyclically  permute the first row by $a$ places and the second row by $b$ places. Concretely, if $S$ is a collection of $p$ tuples of the form $(x,n),(y,m)$ then $(a,b)S=$ is the collection of tuples of the form $(x,n+a),(y,m+b)$. One can see that if $C\in \mathcal C$ is not the board obtained by checking all in the first row and nothing in the last, or checking all in the second row and nothing in the last, ${\rm stab}\, a=1$. Thus, if we remove these two elements from $\mathcal C$, which has cardinality $\binom{2p}p$, we get a set of size $\binom {2p}p-2$ which by the orbit-stabilizer theorem is partitioned into sets of size $p^2=|\Bbb Z_p\times \Bbb Z_p|$, which proves the claim.

Answer (score 9):

The easy way: in characteristic $p$, we have

$$(x+y)^{2p} = (x^p+y^p)^2= x^{2p} + 2x^py^p + y^{2p}.$$

Thus ${2p \choose p} \equiv 2 \mod p$.

Comment: I don't quite understand. How does $(x+y)^{2p} = (x^p+y^p)^2$, and how does this prove the conclusion? Do you mean $(x+y)^{2p} \equiv (x^p+y^p)^2 \pmod{p}$?

Comment: @user3213784 In characteristic $p$, we have $(x+y)^p = x^p+y^p$. This is sometimes known as [Freshman's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream#Prime_characteristic). It proves the conclusion by comparing what I wrote with the usual binomial expansion of $(x+y)^{2p}$.

Comment: @user3213784 But sure, you can replace $=$ with $\equiv \mod p$ if you prefer.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @BrunoJoyal [ABC](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/26489/abc) seems to be at it. I have already called this behaviour out on meta.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff As long as there is nothing wrong with my answer, I am happy.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal If it [helps](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10474/downvoting-to-order).

Comment: @BrunoJoyal I kinda feel that the extra line "It proves the conclusion by comparing [what I wrote] with the usual binomial expansion of $(x+y)^{2p}$" in some form belongs in the answer, in case it isn't obvious right away. It saves time in reading it in this case, improves clarity as such and isn't much extra effort on your part :) But I have no problems with the proof!

Answer (score 4):

Another "easy way" by [Lucas' theorem](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem):

$${2p \choose p} \equiv {2 \choose 1} \equiv 2 \pmod p$$

I'll elaborate since you indicate that you are new to number theory. Lucas' theorem says the following: Let $m$ and $n$ be numbers expressed in base $p$, and let $m_i$ and $n_i$ correspond to the digit in the $i$th place of $m$ and $n$, respectively. Then ${m \choose n} = \displaystyle \prod_i^n {m_i \choose n_i} \pmod p$

In this case, in base $p$, $2p = 20_p$ and $p = 10_p$. Therefore,

$${2p \choose p} \equiv {2 \choose 1}{0 \choose 0} \equiv 2 \pmod p$$

Answer (score 2):

An elementary method to prove this is to note that;
$$p+1\equiv 1\pmod{p}$$
$$p+2\equiv 2\pmod{p}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$2p-1\equiv p-1\pmod{p}.$$

Multiplying all these Equivalences gives us;
\begin{align*}
(p+1)(p+2)\cdots(2p-1)
&\equiv 1\cdot2\cdots(p-1)\pmod{p}\\
&\equiv (p-1)!\pmod{p}.
\end{align*}

Hence, we can say that;
$$p\mid (p+1)(p+2)\cdots(2p-1)-(p-1)!$$
$$\implies p\mid \frac{(p+1)(p+2)\cdots(2p-1)-(p-1)!}{(p-1)!}$$
$$\implies p\mid \frac{(p+1)(p+2)\cdots(2p-1)}{(p-1)!}-1$$
$$\implies \frac{(p+1)(p+2)\cdots(2p-1)}{(p-1)!}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$$
$$\implies \frac{(p+1)(p+2)\cdots(2p-1)(2p)}{(p-1)!(2p)}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$$
$$\implies \frac{(p+1)(p+2)\cdots(2p-1)(2p)}{(p-1)!(p)}\equiv 2\pmod{p}$$
$$\implies \frac{(p+1)(p+2)\cdots(2p-1)(2p)}{(p)!}\equiv 2\pmod{p}$$
$$\implies \frac{(2p)!}{(p)!^2}\equiv 2\pmod{p}$$
$$\implies \binom{2p}{p}\equiv 2\pmod{p}.$$

Hence, we know that $p$ divides $\binom{2p}{p}-2,$ as required.