# Prove that, if $p$ is an odd prime number, then ${f(p)}=\binom{2p-1}{p-1}-1$ is divisible by $p^2$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove that, if $p$ is an odd prime number, then ${f(p)}=\binom{2p-1}{p-1}-1$ is divisible by $p^2$.

---

This is a question that was asked to me in a Permutations and Combinations test. I don't know how to solve it.I have heard that a combinatorial argument can be used to prove this. I would appreciate such an argument as well.

[Bill D: to aid search: this is attributed to Babbage. A stronger version is [Wolstenholme's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem)]

Comment: Well, an obvious first step is to try to prove that it is divisible by $p$.

Comment: $\dbinom{2p-1}{p-1}=\dfrac{(p+1)(p+2)\cdots(p+p-1)}{(p-1)!}=\dfrac{Np^2+ap}{(p-1)!}+1\Rightarrow END$ (because it is known that $a$ is divisible by $p$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enough to show that $2\cdot(\, \binom{2p-1}{p-1}-1) $ is divisible by $p^2$, or, equivalently, 
$\binom{2p}{p}-2 $ is. Recall that we have
$\binom{2p}{p}=\sum_{k+l=p} \binom{p}{k}\binom{p}{l}$, so 
$$\binom{2p}{p}-2=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{k}\binom{p}{p-k}$$ and each term is a product of two factors divisible by $p$. We are done.

$\bf{Added:}$
With the same method we can see easily that $$\binom{ap}{bp}-\binom{a}{b} $$ is divisible by $p^2$. This follows from the equality
$$\binom{ap}{bp}=\sum_{k_1+\cdots k_a=bp} \prod_{i=1}^a \binom{p}{k_i}$$
On RHS, there are $\binom{a}{b}$ terms equal to $1$. Every other term contains at least two factors divisible by $p$.

Comment: (+1) Nice use of Vandermonde! This method can also be used to get the result in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Note that 
$$\binom{2p}{p}=\frac{2p}{p}\binom{2p-1}{p-1}=2\binom{2p-1}{p-1}$$

Thus it suffices to show that 
$$\binom{2p}{p} \equiv 2 \pmod{p^2}$$

This can be proven combinatorically like in the first [answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726845/proof-that-2p-choose-p-equiv-2-pmod-p)

Comment: I'm really not that well versed with number theory so it would be a great help if you could explain the step where you directly said "Thus it suffices to show that...."

Comment: @Aditya: the original question is to show that $\binom{2p-1}{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p^2}$, which is the same as $\binom{2p}{p}=2\binom{2p-1}{p-1}\equiv2\pmod{p^2}$.

Comment: Yes, I get it. But  how does $\binom{2p}{p}$=$\frac{2p}{p}\binom{2p-1}{p-1}$ imply that $p^2$ divides $\binom{2p-1}{p-1}$ ?

Comment: I didn't say that $p^2$ divides $\binom{2p-1}{p-1}$. I am saying that $p^2 | \binom{2p}{p}-2$ by the link posted. Now, you have $$\binom{2p}{p}-2=2 \left( \binom{2p-1}{p-1}-1 \right)$$ is divisible by $p^2$, and since $p$ is odd....

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\qmod}[1]{\quad\left(\mathrm{mod}\ #1\right)} \newcommand{\rmod}[1]{\left(\mathrm{mod}\ #1\right)}$
The Binomial Theorem shows that
$$
\frac{(x+p)^k-x^k}p\equiv kx^{k-1}\pmod{p}\tag1
$$
and, when $p$ is a prime, Fermat's Little Theorem shows that
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(x-k)=x^{p-1}+(p-1)!+p\sum_{k=1}^{p-2}a_kx^k\tag2
$$
Applying $(1)$ to $(2)$ says
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(x+p-k)-\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(x-k)
&\equiv (x+p)^{p-1}-x^{p-1}&\rmod{p^2}\\
&\equiv p(p-1)x^{p-2}&\rmod{p^2}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Setting $x=np$ in $(3)$, for $p\ge3$, gives
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}((n+1)p-k)\equiv\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(np-k)\qmod{p^2}\tag4
$$
which, by induction, shows that
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(np-k)\equiv(p-1)!\qmod{p^2}\tag5
$$
which says that
$$
\binom{np-1}{p-1}\equiv1\qmod{p^2}\tag6
$$

Answer (score 2):

Following comment of @Piquito, we write,
$$\binom{2p-1}{p-1} = \frac{(2p-1)!}{p!(p-1)!}$$
$$ = \frac{(p+1)(p+2)\cdots(p+p-2)(p+p-1)}{(p-1)!}$$
Now, multiply out the product in numerator, first multiplying all the second terms, we get $1\times2\times3\times\cdots\times(p-2)\times(p-1)=(p-1)!$

Now, terms containing $p$ are $p(2\times3\times\cdots\times(p-2)\times(p-1)), p(1\times3\times\cdots\times(p-2)\times(p-1)), p(1\times2\times4\times\cdots\times(p-2)\times(p-1)),...$

Sum of all terms containing a single $p$ is therefore,
$$p\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{(p-1)!}{i}$$
which is divisible by $p^2$ (follows from **Claim**) and all the remaining terms are divisible by $p^2$. Hence, required number is 
$$\binom{2p-1}{p-1}-1=\frac{Np^2+(p-1)!}{(p-1)!}-1$$
for some natural number $N$, which is divisible by $p^2$, as desired.

**Claim:** $p\Big|\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{(p-1)!}{i}$

**Proof:** Let $1\leq i\leq p-1$ and let $j$ be its multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb Z_p$. Then, $$\frac{(p-1)!}{i}\equiv -j\pmod p$$

Now, since $\mathbb Z_p$ is a field, the list of multiplicative inverses of elements in $\mathbb Z_p\setminus 0$ is $\mathbb Z_p\setminus 0$. Therefore, 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{(p-1)!}{i}\equiv \sum_{j=1}^{p-1}-j\pmod p$$
$$\equiv -\frac{p(p-1)}{2}\pmod p$$
$$\equiv 0\pmod p$$

Hence proved