# Combination modular arithmetic proof

Tags: solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

What's wrong with the following solution?

Problem: Let $p$ be an odd prime number. Prove $$\binom{2p-1}{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$$

Solution: It is equivalent to proving $$(2p-1)! \equiv p!(p-1)! \pmod{p^2}$$

Since $\gcd((p-1)!, p^2) = 1$, we can divide both sides by $(p-1)!$ to get $$p! \equiv p! \pmod{p^2}$$ which is obviously true.

Comment: The 1st step is wrong. $a/b\equiv c\bmod m$ is equivalent to $a\equiv bc\bmod{bm}$.

Comment: Also $(2p-1)!$ when divided by $(p-1)!$ is NOT $p!$

Comment: Related: [Prove that, if $p$ is an odd prime number, then ${f(p)}=\binom{2p-1}{p-1}-1$ is divisible by $p^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3473865/prove-that-if-p-is-an-odd-prime-number-then-fp-binom2p-1p-1-1-is)